# Javascript function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting  error. My Javascript function returns undefined  while it alert correct within the  function.
On my 1st controller i am calling like this.

```
 CustomerService.setName(data.name);
```

And on Service page like this

```
service.setName = function(name){ 
  var user = name; 
   alert(user); 
  return user;
}
```

I am accessing this return value on my 2nd controller like this.

```
$scope.name = CustomerService.setName(name);
```

*CustomerService is service name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using get/set

In your service you can have

```
app.service("CustomerService", function() {  

    var service = {}; 
    service.setName = function(name){ 
        user = name; 
        // optional return if you feel the need to
    }
    service.getName = function(){
        return user;
    }
    return service;
})
```

Your current `service.setName` doesn't persist the `name` cause it's being stored in a locally variable.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no argument given in the following even though the function needs that.

```
$scope.name = CustomerService.setName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a variable with "var" creates a local variable, so when you call the function again, the value is not there anymore. Only when you give an argument with the function, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided any parameter to this function service.setName(). So name is set to undefined , which causes the function to return undefined.